# Using Session ID

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a session ID in use after a user logs in. The session allows me to show their User ID on dashboard page after a successful login. I now want to show other attributes from the SQL table on the dashboard table. Can i get help on how i can adjust my code to show email and name on the dashboard page alongside their ID.

Login page:

```
try
{
    string uid = TextBox1.Text;
    string pass = TextBox2.Text;

    myCon.Open();
    string qry = "select userId from users where userId='" + uid + "' and Password='" + pass + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, myCon);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr.Read())
    {
        Session["userId"] = uid.Trim();
        Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Label4.Text = "UserId & Password Is not correct Try again..!!";
    }

    myCon.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Dashboard landing page after a successful login attempt:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["userId"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

    SessionLabel.Text = "Username : " + Session["userId"];
}

protected void ButtonLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: [**SQL Injection alert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could put a class into session with all the information from that user table.

So, say this:

```
public class clsUser
{

   public DataTable rstUser = new DataTable();

   public clsUser(int UserID)
   {
       string strSQL =
           "SELECT * FROM users WHERE useriD = @ID";
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyDB))
       {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserID;
               conn.Open();
               rstUser.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
           }
       }
   }
   public int userID
   {
       get { return (int)rstUser.Rows[0]["ID"]; }
   }

   public string UserName
   {
       get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
   }

   public string FirstName
   {
       get { return (string)rstUser.Rows[0]["FirstName"]; }
   }
   public string LastName
   {
       get { return (string)rstUser.Rows[0]["LastName"]; }
   }

   public string Email
   {
       get { return (string)rstUser.Rows[0]["Email"]; }
   }

   public bool IsAdmin
   {
       get { return (bool)rstUser.Rows[0]["IsAdmin"]; }
   }
```

}

So, then in code? At logon time, you have the "id", and thus save the above into session.

```
        clsUser MyUser = new clsUser(UserID);
        Session["MyUser"] = MyUser;
```

Now, anywhere in code, you can go:

```
        clsUser MyUserTest = (clsUser)Session["MyUser"];

        Debug.Print($"User id = {MyUserTest.userID}");
        Debug.Print($"First Name = {MyUserTest.FirstName}");
        Debug.Print($"Email = {MyUserTest.Email}");
        Debug.Print($"Is admin = {MyUserTest.IsAdmin.ToString()}");
```